# Prolog: count iteration in binary search tree

Tags: recursion, prolog, binary-search-tree

I have a predicate that get a bst T in input and return a list S of the values contained in the bst that belong to a specific range [R1,R2] and this works fine. When I try to count the iteration done in order to get the list in output I receive Always false. This is my predicate's code:

```
findExamsInRange(R1, R2, T, S, N) :-
   find(R1, R2, T, S, N),
   N > 0.

find(R1, R2, nil, [], N).  
find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :-
   V >= R1,
   V =< R2,
   find(R1,R2, L, L,NL),
   find(R1,R2, R, LR,NR),
   append([V|LL], LR, S),
   N is NL+NR+1.  
find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :-
   V < R1,
   find(R1, R2, R, S, N).
find(R1, R2, t(V,L,R), S, N) :-
   V > R2,
   find(R1, R2, L, S, N).
```

Can anyone help me why I cannot get the value of `N`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the first clause of the `find/5` predicate:

```
find(R1, R2, nil, [], N).
```

be instead:

```
find(_R1, _R2, nil, [], 0).
```

When reaching the leaves of the tree, you have to return a value for `N` that allows the `N is NL+NR+1` goal to succeed without errors.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `assert` and `retract` to define a global counter :

```
inc_counter:- % normal case
    retract(counter(X)), !,
    Y is X+1,
    assert(counter(Y)).
inc_counter:- % if counter is not defined yet
    assert(counter(1)).
```

You then place `inc_counter` in the clauses whose iterations you want to count, and query the end result using `counter(X)`.